# Ignore dollar currency sign ($) in decimal field with Filehelpers library

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Suppose I have a Filehelpers class like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class SomeRecord
{
    public string Field1;
    public decimal Field2;
}
```

If I try to import a CSV record like this:

```
hello,$4.00
```

I get a `FileHelpers.ConvertException`: "Error Converting '$4.00' to type: 'Decimal'."

How can I make Filehelpers ignore the $ sign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd need to write your own converter and use that converter for `Field2`. This isn't that difficult, all you need to do is create a class that extends `ConverterBase`. For example:

```
public class CurrencyConverter : ConverterBase
{
    private NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();

    public CurrencyConverter()
    {
        nfi.NegativeSign = "-";
        nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
        nfi.CurrencySymbol = "$";
    }

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        return decimal.Parse(from, NumberStyles.Currency, nfi);
    }
}
```

You can then use that converter on your `Field2` property:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class SomeRecord
{
    public string Field1;
    [FieldConverter(typeof(CurrencyConverter))]
    public decimal Field2;
}
```

and the $4.00 will be parsed as 4.00.

Obivously my code above isn't that robust. You may prefer to use `TryParse` rather than just `Parse` and return `0` if it fails but you get the idea.

Comment: Great, thanks, Pete. Works as advertised. I don't think it needs a `TryParse`. It would be appropriate to get an exception on bad data.